# certbot Failed authorization procedure error

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, virtual-machine, certbot

I've been trying to secure my website (made in an UBUNTU 18.04 VM) with an SSL certificate, sadly at the end of the process, when trying to do a dry run and it throws me this :

> Attempting to renew cert (website.intelag.net) from
>   /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/website.intelag.net.conf produced an
>   unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. website.intelag.net
>   (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks
>   sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from
>   http://website.intelag.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/lzg1XNdb_9GsFmmN1YcixRNTUoKW8tl3YvR735LafTg:
>   "

Answer (score 2):

I have stuck with the same problem. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and server is NGNX.
According to your error certbot tries to authorize your website by visiting http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/some-key

You have to **allow access to '.well-known/acme-challenge/' folder from Web**. If you are using NGNX go to '/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf' and add the next lines inside 'server' block after 'server_name' and 'listen' definition:

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {

    default_type "text/plain";
    root /var/www/letsencrypt;  #create this folder if it does not exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that I had 2 enabled configurations for the same site or `ServerName`.

This passes `apache2ctl configtest` but it confuses `letsencrypt`, it also would confuse systems admins.
So I disabled and removed the duplicate and it worked correctly.